# reimer tieman reaction only one ortho product

Tags: organic-chemistry, aromatic-compounds, phenols, carbene

**why we cannot have two reimer tiemann substitutions on the same phenol 
 as CHO- group is electron withdrawing it wont disturb electron concentration at its meta which is phenol's ortho- product**

Comment: But it deactivates the system overall

Comment: If you look at the electron flow, you'd see the electron density on  $\ce{O}$ in $\ce{Ar-OH}$ is not completely available after the first substitution.

Comment: why am i getting down votes? you guys find it difficult to help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some literature evidence that shows to have two Reimer–Tiemann substitutions on same phenol ring could be possible. For example, salicilic acid is a Reimer–Tiemann product from phenol and carbon tetrachloride. Yet, it had undergone another Reimer–Tiemann reaction to give  5-formyl-2-hydroxybenzoic acid with $17\%$ yield (para-substitution) but no 3-formyl-2-hydroxybenzoic acid (ortho-substitution) when chloroform was replaced by trichloroacetic acid (*J. Chem. Soc.*, **1933**, 496-500).

For more examples: Read, [*Chem. Rev.*, **1960**, *60(2)*, 169–184](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/cr60204a003).

[*J. Chem. Soc.*, **1933**, 496-500](http://pubs.rsc.org/en/content/articlepdf/1933/jr/jr9330000496).